# UnauthorizedAccessException when using getAccessControl

Tags: c#, ownership, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm trying to copy files from external hard disk to folder in my desktop, in order to do that I have to take ownership of the folders and the files in the external hard disk, I read in previous questions about it how it has to be and my code looks like this:

```
using (new ProcessPrivileges.PrivilegeEnabler(Process.GetCurrentProcess(), Privilege.TakeOwnership))
{
    directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    directorySecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();

    directorySecurity.SetOwner(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User);
    Directory.SetAccessControl(path, directorySecurity);    
}
```

When I run this code I get an exception in the line:

```
directorySecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
```

The exception is:

> "unauthorizedAccessException was caught" "Attempted to perform an
>   unauthorized operation".

Why is that happen? And how can I copy these folders and files?

Comment: Does your user account have permissions to alter the ACL of directories and files? If not, then it would of course not work. You might want to try running your program with administrator privileges and see what happens. (Remember that when running as administrator, your program will likely use the administrator's desktop folder as destination...)

Comment: "I'm trying to copy files from external hard disk to folder in my desktop, in order to do that I have to take ownership of the folders and the files in the external hard disk" => Why?  you need read permissions but not ownership.  Also if you have the rights to take ownership you have the rights to grant yourself read perms if you don't have them, taking ownership seems an overkill.